# BackboneJS How to use parameter inside View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Backbone Collection, which returns a given number of models and now I have a "load More" button which should load more models. The Collection which is loaded is based on a parameter. My issue is, that when Collection is loaded, in the Views `initialize` function I'm able to get the parameter which the Collection is based on. This parameter though, is needed in my "loadMore" function. So, my question is, how can I pass a parameter from the `initialize` function to a another function?

This is what I got so far:

```
MyStuff.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({           
    url: 'someUrl',
    initialize: function(opts) {
         opts = opts || {};
         this.value= opts.value;
    },
    step: 0,
    parse: function(response){
        var slice = response.results.slice(this.step*8,(this.step+1)*8);
        this.step++;
        return slice;
    }       
});

MyStuff.View= Backbone.View.extend({
    template: 'myTemplate',
    initialize: function() {    
        this.currentPage = 0;           
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.hideLoader);
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.afterRender);
        this.collection.reset(this.collection.shuffle(), {silent:true});
        var suit = this.collection.toJSON()[0]; // HERE I GET MY VALUE!!                
    },
    events: {
        'click .loadMore': 'loadMore'
    }

    loadMore: function(opts){
        this.showLoader();
        this.currentPage++;
        this.collection.fetch({url: this.collection.url + '?page='+ this.currentPage + '&value=' // HERE I NEED MY VALUE!!!! //, remove: false});
        this.collection.fetch({remove: false});
        this.render();
      }
});

return MyStuff;
```

Comment: Define a getter method returning that value (`this.value`) and call it in View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.suit = this.collection.toJSON()[0].nameOfYourKey;

'&value=' + this.suit
```

You can access things you put on `this` which is your view instance pointer.

Comment: hmm... this gives me `&value=[object%20Object]` ... :-/

Comment: yes I got confused because of the formatting, I fixed it to make it clearer - it looked like loadMore was outside the view

Comment: this means that `this.collection.toJSON()[0]` is pointing to the wrong thing. Just above it on a new line write `debugger;` and then run it in Chrome. In the console when it breaks on that line paste in `this.collection.toJSON()[0]` and see what it is

Comment: Note that if you are trying to access something you should probably be doing something like `this.collection.at(0).get('something')` which will get attributes from the first model. To see what is in your models do `console.log(this.collection.models)` and check `attributes` on the models

Comment: Hmm like mentioned in the description, `this.collection.toJSON()[0]` gives me the key value which I need... the attributes in the models doesnt matter...

Comment: So you know the key? You didn't say what is in the array at [0]. If it's an object with a key you want to access it would be `this.collection.toJSON()[0].keyName` - though like I said the normal way of doing this would be from a model, since your JSON is parsed into models if used correctly

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right! I figured out the same! So problem solved! If you want, you can write it as answer and I will accept it! :-)